# Scaling and stretching SVG to four arbitrary corners

Tags: matrix, svg, geometry, transform

I have an SVG image (a site plan) with width `w`, height `h`, which I would like to view on a map background.

To superimpose it at the right place on the map, I would like to stretch it to four arbitrary corners: `x1,y1`, `x2,y2`, `x3,y3`, `x4,y4`.

I figure I might be able to do this with a combination of SVG transforms (scale, rotate, skew, translate) but my maths is nowhere near up to the job. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotation and translation can describe [Euclidean (i.e. length-preserving) transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation). With isotropic scaling added in you obtain [similarity transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_transformation_%28disambiguation%29), and with anisotropic scaling and skewing you even get [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). So that is the kind of transformation your operations can express.

But an affine transformation is already uniquely defined by *three* points and their images. Which means the fourth corner will end up in a location determined by the other three. To arbitrarily position four corners, you need a [projective transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_transformation).

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/35416) about hwo to compute a projective transformation, how to apply it, and how to use it in JavaScript, if the browser supports projective transformations in 3D.

Comment: Superbly helpful. Thank you very much!